# Interfacing 32nos. of analog signals to PIC24EP**814 Microcontroller

Tags: c, pic24

How can I interface 32 nos. of analog channels or signals to a PIC 24EP***814 Microcontroller?

Comment: Can you add more details? You could use multiplexer(s), external ADCs...

Comment: The PIC24EP521GU814 should have enough channels.